# actualizar version django de un proyecto

Tags: python, django

¿cual es la manera correcta de actualizar la versión de python y django de un proyecto antiguo ? generar un entorno virtual mas actualizado e ir corrigiendo los errores que se generan por el cambio de versión ? la verdad soy super nuevo en el tema, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿De qué versiones estamos hablando? Si pasas de Python 2 a Python 3 hay código que deberás ir modificando, pues son versiones con partes incompatibles.

Comment: de python 2.7 a 2.7.6 y de  Django==1.5.12 a 1.8.7

Comment: Django cambia mucho de la versión 1.5 a la 1.8, yo te recomendaría no actualizarla porque vas a tener que reescribir muchísimas cosas. En la versión 1.7 modificaron la forma de leer el fichero settings, entre otras cosas. Si de todas formas quieres actualizarlo, crea un proyecto nuevo, crea el entorno virtual y migra la carpeta con el código al nuevo proyecto. Una vez hecho esto, tendrás que reinstalar todos los packages que tengas, en vez de instalar django 1.5, instala django 1.8. Suerte.